# Range aggregation on multiple field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two fields in the search document such as `salary_from` and `salary_to` and want the aggregation of salary ranges such as 0 - 10 , 10 - 20, etc.

Is there any ways to set multiple fields to the Elastic Range Aggregation. (I can set one field by using `setField` function)

I just need to get the aggregated count of salary ranges or slabs by considering the two fields `salary_from` and `salary_to`.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please explain your use case with a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, below is what you need.

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "salary_ranges": {
         "terms": {
            "script": "doc['salary_from'].value + ' to ' + doc['salary_to'].value",
            "size": 0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It basically uses a script for `Terms Aggregation`. Read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script).

If say, you have 3 documents with `salary_from` set to 3 and `salary_to` set to 5 and then you have 2 documents with `salary_from` set to 10 and `salary_to` set to 25, the result of the query above will look something like below:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 5,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "salary_ranges": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "3 to 5",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "10 to 25",
               "doc_count": 2
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```